# Сокращенная запись for if

Tags: python

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
b = sum(a)/len(a)
k = 0    
for i in a:
        k += i <= b
print(k)
```

Как можно сократить конструкцию for чтобы получилось нечто:

```
 k += for i in a i <= b
```

Comment: k = sum([i <= b for i in a])

Comment: Вы представили другое логическое решение. Один из вариантов для конкретно этой задачи, а в общем есть еще вариант? Как например
print(a if True else b)
Здесь мы вложили в print() if
можно ли так вложить for в "="  не применяя списков :) ?

Comment: `k = sum(i <= b for i in a)` - можно без списков ;)

Comment: @Евгений *можно ли так вложить for в "="* - я думаю, что в такой конструкции не очень много смысла. for же просто переберет значения -  если вам нужны все, вы сделаете лист. А иначе на выходе вы получите переменную с последним значением в цикле. Слишком сложно для такого результата

Comment: @eri, да про генераторы я забыл :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается так

```
k = sum(i <= b for i in a)
```

Но похоже хочется изучить синтаксис вложения if в строчный for

```
k = sum(1 for i in a if i <= b)
```

Можно и через map,reduce

```
functools.reduce(lambda k,x: k+x, map(lambda i: i<=b , a)
```

Comment: А зачем свёртка? `sum` умеет работать с итерируемыми объектами, в т.ч. с `map`. Ещё скобку не закрыли)

Comment: пример с сум уже есть. вот если надо чтото кроме сложения